# AngularJS ui-routing project - from https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/#resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to make a sample app using AngularJS ui-routing.
I'm using a tutorial from here: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/#resources
I'm getting errors in the console when I run the site locally in Chrome.

Here are the errors:

- Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state
  object with URL
  'file:///Users/******/Desktop/ui-routes-site/index.html#/index.html'
  cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'
- Error: Circular dependency: uiViewDirective
- Error: Circular dependency: uiSrefDirective

I'm not too sure what to do because I just copied the files from the tutorial.
If anyone has seen something like this before or knows about circular errors with Angular, please help!

What my code looks like:

```
//index.html

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
        // For Component users, it should look like this:
        // var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-ui-router')]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ui-view></div>
  <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
  <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// js/app.js
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

---

```
//partials/state1.html
<h1>State 1</h1>
</hr>
<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

---

```
//partials/state1.list.html
<h3>List of State 1 Items</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
//js/angular-ui-router.min.js
 /**
 * State-based routing for AngularJS
 * @version v0.2.18
 * @link http://angular-ui.github.com/
 * @license MIT License, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/* commonjs package manager support (eg componentjs) */
if (typeof module !== "undefined" && typeof exports !== "undefined" && module.exports === exports){
  module.exports = 'ui.router';
}

(function (window, angular, undefined) {
/*jshint globalstrict:true*/
/*global angular:false*/
'use strict';

var isDefined = angular.isDefined,
    isFunction = angular.isFunction,
    isString = angular.isString,
    isObject = angular.isObject,
    isArray = angular.isArray,
    forEach = angular.forEach,
    extend = angular.extend,
    copy = angular.copy,
    toJson = angular.toJson;

function inherit(parent, extra) {
  return extend(new (extend(function() {}, { prototype: parent }))(), extra);
}

function merge(dst) {
  forEach(arguments, function(obj) {
    if (obj !== dst) {
      forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
        if (!dst.hasOwnProperty(key)) dst[key] = value;
      });
    }
  });
  return dst;
}

/**
 * Finds the common ancestor path between two states.
 *
 * @param {Object} first The first state.
 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In you app.js, change

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp');
```